# Primefaces Rating, the rated value not passing to backing bean

Tags: primefaces

I've the following code for ratings:

```
<h:form>
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"></p:growl>
       <h:outputLabel value="Rating:" />
        <p:rating value = "#{ratingBean.rating}" stars="5"  rendered="true">
           <p:ajax event="rate" listener="#{ratingBean.onrate}" update="messages" />  
    </p:rating>
</h:form>
```

And my backing bean goes like this:

package backupController;

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primefaces.event.RateEvent;


@Named
@RequestScoped
public class RatingBean implements Serializable {


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Integer getRating() {
        System.out.println("You Rated: "+ rating);
        return rating;

    }

    public void setRating(Integer rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
        System.out.println("You Rated re:");

    }


  public void onrate(RateEvent rateEvent) {  
      FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Rate Event", "You rated:" + ((Integer) rateEvent.getRating()).intValue());  

      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);  
  } 

//    public void oncancel() {  
//        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cancel Event", "Rate Reset");  
//  
//        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);  
//    }  

    private Integer rating;

}
```

I'm getting information message that I've rated but in the console the value is rated null. The  displays the information on my xhtml page along with the rating but bean is not reading the value.

Answer (score 4):

RequestScoped is not wide enough for what you want to achieve.  For every rate you make new request is sent to a Web Server, and so, new request scoped bean is created. Try view scoped bean

Comment: Ok since you're new here please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problems